# How many data types of integer are there in pySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

How many data types of integer in the dataframe in pySpark ? And what are the range of them?
If I use the short type instead of long, will it have less cost for the memory ?

Answer (score 2):

These are all the numeric data type available in pyspark

```
BinaryType, DecimalType, DoubleType, FloatType, ByteType, IntegerType, LongType, ShortType
```

Comment: if this helped can you accept as an answer? @yanachen